# How to load local files in node-webkit webview

Tags: javascript, html, webview, node-webkit

Is it possible to load local html files using **webview** in node-webkit ? If possible how to achieve the same.

I tried creating object URL using Blob and assigning it to the "src" of webview but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, `<webview />` is a chrome app only tag. meaning it's special implementation of chrome and not available in the chromium project (which NW.js is based on)

Seems like it's a [known issue](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/3849)